# Search results are wrong?

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to make a research function,within a JSP page that by default displays all recordings. I added a form that submits to the same page,to show coherent search results if there is a search input,or simply display all recordings,as i said on top .

Whenever i search,this happens:

- If the searched term has results,it displays only the last recording
- If the searched term has no results,it doesn't display anything(that's normal)

This is my code :

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="searchinput" placeholder="Search...">
</form>

<% String recordingsXML = getRecordings(null);
SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
org.jdom2.Document doc = saxBuilder.build(new StringReader(recordingsXML));
org.jdom2.Element racine = doc.getRootElement();
List listRecordingsLues = racine.getChildren("recording");
Iterator<org.jdom2.Element> i = listRecordingsLues.iterator();
String keyword = request.getParameter("searchinput");
if (keyword != null && keyword.length() >0) {

while(i.hasNext()) {

if(i.next().getChild("name").getText().indexOf(keyword)!=-1) {

org.jdom2.Element p = i.next();%>
<%String titre = p.getChild("name").getText();%>
<%String description = p.getChild("description").getText();%>
<%String duree = p.getChild("length").getText();%>
<%String recordID = p.getChild("recordID").getText();%>
<li>
<b>Titre :</b> <%=titre%>                 
<b>Description :</b> <%=description%>
<b>Durée :</b> <%=duree%>
<a href="foo?meetingId=<%=recordID%>"></a>  
</li>
<%}}%>

<%}else {

while(i.hasNext()) {

org.jdom2.Element p = i.next();%>
<%String titre = p.getChild("name").getText();%>
<%String description = p.getChild("description").getText();%>
<%String duree = p.getChild("length").getText();%>
<%String recordID = p.getChild("recordID").getText();%>
<li>
<b>Titre :</b> <%=titre%>                 
<b>Description :</b> <%=description%>
<b>Durée :</b> <%=duree%>
<a href="foo?meetingId=<%=recordID%>"></a>  
</li>

<%}}%>
```

Please note that,if i load the page,normally without any search input,or if i put a null input,it displays all recordings,as normal,so that can't be the problem.

Any suggestions please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `java != javascript` ... careful with your question tagging

Comment: yeah sorry,i obviously instapicked javascript by mistake,thanks for the edit thought,it helps.

Comment: How does your data looks?

Comment: What do you mean by how it looks?
in the script,its called as a string,if that's what you are asking for.

Comment: How does the data of listRecordingsLues look? I mean what's the searched data exactly?

Comment: we are looking for a string(listRevordingsLues is a list of recordings as stings). Please note that the else is working extremely fine,so basically the error comes not from the data,but from the way i am looking into it,and i can't seem to figure out what am i doing wrong,so you can see for the else to understand more of the code,it works just fine,it uploads every recording we have.